# Map State lifecycle in a keyed process function or windowed stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is MapState content automatically cleared up after the window expires or when onTimer function  for that particular key is called or it has to be manually cleared given a TTL config is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any state you register yourself and that doesn't have TTL defined will be retained indefinitely.

Flink's built-in windows are cleaned up automatically, but windows you implement yourself in a KeyedProcessFunction using MapState need to be manually cleared when they are no longer useful.